# How to use the merge function properly?

Tags: c++, opencv

I've used the `cv::merge()` function at the end of the following code, but it throws an unhandled exception when the compiler reaches to the `cv::merge()` function call.

I've tried both `cv::Mat[]` array and vector of `cv::Mat` as inputs, but it is still throws the C++ exception.

The purpose of the code is to extract the red channel of an underwater image,  and apply some new values in order to enhance color distribution according to [equation 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfIPb.png) of this reference (Color Correction Based on CFA and Enhancement Based on Retinex With Dense Pixels for Underwater Images).

It only works with `cv::merge(planes, 1, image2)`; which returns one page of `planes` in `image2`. It must merge three planes in `planes` into `image2` to give a color image not a gray.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    //read an image
    Mat image = imread("9554.png", 1);
    //check for existence of data
    if (!image.data) 
    { printf("no image data.\n"); return -1; }
    //planes is a vector for holding rgb channels separately
    //std::vector<Mat> planes;
    Mat planes[3];

    //split the image into channels
    //planes[2] is the red channel
    split(image, planes);

    // converting planes from uchar to double
    planes[0].convertTo(planes[0], CV_64FC1);
    planes[1].convertTo(planes[1], CV_64FC1);
    planes[2].convertTo(planes[2], CV_64FC1);

    // defining coefficients of green and blue channel for blending
    double a = 0.05, b = 0.95;
    
    //sum_im stores pixelwise sum of Red, Green and Blue planes
    Mat imBlendNormal_B_G, sum_im;

    //converting to double
    imBlendNormal_B_G.convertTo(imBlendNormal_B_G, CV_64FC1);
    sum_im.convertTo(sum_im, CV_64FC1);

    //blending green and blue planes with a and b coefficients
    // and 0.0 offset(or gamma)
    addWeighted(planes[1], a, planes[0], b, 0.0, imBlendNormal_B_G);

    // sum of red, green and blue pixel in two addWeighted calls
    addWeighted(planes[2], 1.0, planes[1], 1.0, 0.0, sum_im);
    addWeighted(planes[0], 1.0, sum_im, 1.0, 0.0, sum_im);

    //dividing blended green and blue image to total RGB sum
    divide(imBlendNormal_B_G, sum_im, imBlendNormal_B_G);

    //defining average kernel 3x3
    Mat avg3x3_kernel = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 1.0 / 9.0, 1.0 / 9.0, 1.0 / 9.0, 1.0 / 9.0, 1.0 / 9.0, 1.0 / 9.0, 1.0 / 9.0, 1.0 / 9.0, 1.0 / 9.0);
    
    //defining matrices for storing 3x3 average of blue and green planes
    Mat blueAverage, greenAverage;
    // converting to double type
    blueAverage.convertTo(blueAverage, CV_64FC1);
    greenAverage.convertTo(greenAverage, CV_64FC1);

    // taking 3x3 average
    filter2D(planes[0], blueAverage, planes[0].depth(), avg3x3_kernel);
    filter2D(planes[1], greenAverage, planes[1].depth(), avg3x3_kernel);

    //imBlendAverage_B_G_R: for blending of averaged green and blue channels
    Mat imBlendAverage_B_G_R; 
    //convert to double
    imBlendAverage_B_G_R.convertTo(imBlendAverage_B_G_R, CV_64FC1);

    //blend averaged green and blue with a and b coeffs
    addWeighted(greenAverage, a, blueAverage, b, 0.0, imBlendAverage_B_G_R);
    
    //differentiate red values
    addWeighted(imBlendAverage_B_G_R, 1.0, planes[2], -1.0, 0.0, imBlendAverage_B_G_R);

    //CompensationTermRed: storing finally compensated red channel intensities
    Mat CompensationTermRed; 
    //coverting to double
    CompensationTermRed.convertTo(CompensationTermRed, CV_64FC1);

    //multiplication term
    CompensationTermRed = imBlendAverage_B_G_R.mul(imBlendNormal_B_G);

    //final add term
    addWeighted(CompensationTermRed, 1.0, planes[2], 1.0, 0.0, CompensationTermRed);

    //convert to uchar
    Mat CompensationTermRed_uint8;
    CompensationTermRed.convertTo(CompensationTermRed_uint8, CV_8UC1);
    //imshow("CompensationTermRed_uint8", CompensationTermRed_uint8);

    // assign new red channel values to planes[2]
    planes[2] = CompensationTermRed_uint8;

    Mat image2 = image;
    cv::merge(planes, 1, image2); 
    image2.convertTo(image2, CV_8UC3);
    imshow("merge",image2);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @AdrianW When using the `opencv` tag, it is requested to add a language specifier, since there are lot of language specific bindings and ports of/for the OpenCV library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging your code, namely inspecting `planes` right before the `cv::merge` call, reveals that `planes[0]` and `planes[1]` are of type `FLOAT64`, whereas `planes[2]` is of type `UINT8`. From the [documentation on `cv::merge`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga7d7b4d6c6ee504b30a20b1680029c7b4):

```
Parameters
    mv  input array of matrices to be merged; all the matrices in mv must have the same size and the same depth.
```

Therefore, you get the exception – and that's also the reason, why `cv::merge(planes, 1, image2)` works nevertheless.

To fix that issue, just get rid of that part:

```cpp
//convert to uchar
Mat CompensationTermRed_uint8;
CompensationTermRed.convertTo(CompensationTermRed_uint8, CV_8UC1);
```

and replace

```cpp
planes[2] = CompensationTermRed_uint8;
```

with

```cpp
planes[2] = CompensationTermRed;
```

Then, your code should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, your answer exactly solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected version of the code that works fine and merge() function throws no unhandled C++ exception. (thanks to comments from HansHirse)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    //read an image
    Mat image = imread("9554.png", 1);
    //check for existance of data
    if (!image.data) 
    { printf("no image data.\n"); return -1; }
    //planes is a vector for holding rgb channels separately
    Mat planes[3];

    //split the image into channels
    //planes[2] is the red channel
    split(image, planes);

    // converting planes from uchar to double
    planes[0].convertTo(planes[0], CV_64FC1);
    planes[1].convertTo(planes[1], CV_64FC1);
    planes[2].convertTo(planes[2], CV_64FC1);

    // defining coefficients of green and blue channel for blending
    double a = 0.05, b = 0.95;
    
    //sum_im stores pixelwise sum of Red, Green and Blue planes
    Mat imBlendNormal_B_G, sum_im;

    //converting to double
    imBlendNormal_B_G.convertTo(imBlendNormal_B_G, CV_64FC1);
    sum_im.convertTo(sum_im, CV_64FC1);

    //blending green and blue planes with a and b coefficients
    // and 0.0 offset(or gamma)
    addWeighted(planes[1], a, planes[0], b, 0.0, imBlendNormal_B_G);

    // sum of red, green and blue pixel in two addWeighted calls
    addWeighted(planes[2], 1.0, planes[1], 1.0, 0.0, sum_im);
    addWeighted(planes[0], 1.0, sum_im, 1.0, 0.0, sum_im);

    //dividing blended green and blue image to total RGB sum
    divide(imBlendNormal_B_G, sum_im, imBlendNormal_B_G);

    //defining average kernel 3x3
    Mat avg3x3_kernel = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 1.0 / 9.0, 1.0 / 9.0, 1.0 / 9.0, 1.0 / 9.0, 1.0 / 9.0, 1.0 / 9.0, 1.0 / 9.0, 1.0 / 9.0, 1.0 / 9.0);
    
    //defining matrices for storing 3x3 average of blue and green planes
    Mat blueAverage, greenAverage;
    // converting to double type
    blueAverage.convertTo(blueAverage, CV_64FC1);
    greenAverage.convertTo(greenAverage, CV_64FC1);

    // taking 3x3 average
    filter2D(planes[0], blueAverage, planes[0].depth(), avg3x3_kernel);
    filter2D(planes[1], greenAverage, planes[1].depth(), avg3x3_kernel);

    //imBlendAverage_B_G_R: for blending of averaged green and blue channels
    Mat imBlendAverage_B_G_R; 
    //convert to double
    imBlendAverage_B_G_R.convertTo(imBlendAverage_B_G_R, CV_64FC1);

    //blend averaged green and blue with a and b coeffs
    addWeighted(greenAverage, a, blueAverage, b, 0.0, imBlendAverage_B_G_R);
    
    //differentiate red values
    addWeighted(imBlendAverage_B_G_R, 1.0, planes[2], -1.0, 0.0, imBlendAverage_B_G_R);

    //CompensationTermRed: storing finally compensated red channel intensities
    Mat CompensationTermRed; 
    //coverting to double
    CompensationTermRed.convertTo(CompensationTermRed, CV_64FC1);

    //multiplication term
    CompensationTermRed = imBlendAverage_B_G_R.mul(imBlendNormal_B_G);

    //final add term
    addWeighted(CompensationTermRed, 1.0, planes[2], 1.0, 0.0, CompensationTermRed);
    
    // assign new red channel values to planes[2]
    planes[2] = CompensationTermRed;

    Mat image2;
    cv::merge(planes, 3, image2); 
    image2.convertTo(image2, CV_8UC3);
    imshow("merge",image2);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;

}
```